# ¿ Archivos de iOs y Android debo subir a una aplicación de Facebook para verificar?

Tags: login, react-native, app, facebook

He leído la documentación de Facebook de como verificar mi aplicación para conseguir el inicio de sesión con Facebook, pero no me queda muy claro y estoy estancada.

Me piden en Facebook que proporcione una versión de iOs y una versión de Android de mi aplicación, pero no se cual es  exactamente  los archivos que debo subir a Facebook para la revisión de los dos S.O.

¿ Cual son los archivos o carpetas de mi proyecto que debo subir a Facebook ?

¿ Existe otra documentación para seguir para crear mi aplicación de Facebook ?

Gracias